# Passing a variable to GraphQL mutation using ApolloClient doesn't seem to work

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to figure out how to run mutations using Apollo Client.

Here's the mutation I'm trying to run:

```
export const CREATE_POST = gql`
    mutation CreatePost($title: String) {
      createPost(
        title: $title
        body: "Test body, whatever..."
      ) {
        title
        body
        slug
      }
    }
`
```

Here's the functional component that renders a form, and tries to run this mutation once I submit the form:

```
export default function post() {
  const [createPost] = useMutation(CREATE_POST)

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { data } = await createPost({
      variables: { title: "test title" }
    })
  }

  return (<rendering the form here>)
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$title" of type "String" used in position expecting type "String!".

If I remove the `$title` variable from here: `mutation CreatePost($title: String) {`, the error disappears. It seems like I'm failing to pass it the variable. But as far as I can tell, this part of the code is correct:

```
    const { data } = await createPost({
      variables: { title: "test title" }
    })
```

That's how you're supposed to pass variables to mutations, right? What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this?

The full code for the component is [here](https://github.com/lumenwrites/godotassets/blob/master/frontend/pages/post/create.tsx)

Query code is [here](https://github.com/lumenwrites/godotassets/blob/master/frontend/apollo/queries.ts)

Comment: `mutation CreatePost($title: String!)` - the same type as mutation arg (read in API)

Comment: @xadm Oh this is perfect, thank you so much, never would've guessed it!

Comment: nothing to guess, information in error, explained many times

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks to @xadm.

Had to use `mutation CreatePost($title: String!)` instead of `mutation CreatePost($title: String)`.